# jpeg to byte array, while conversion logic is inside if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, scope, arrays, memorystream

I'm sure this is a very simple issue that even inexperienced developers would be able to do, but I'm just starting out.

I've put an if statement round the logic to convert a jpeg into a byte array so that the conversion doesn't happen unless there is a file selected. But this makes the variable `logoBytes` invisible to the data parameter. 
A colleague told me I would have to put the logic for the conversion into a method, and then reference that method somewhere, but I'm still rather confused.

```
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Div1.Visible = true;

if (logoPrvw.Value != null)
{ 
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(logoPrvw.Value);
    byte[] logoBytes;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        logoBytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
TemplateData data = new TemplateData(txtSchemeCode.Text, txtVersion.Text, txtComment.Text, txtTemplateId.Text, logoBytes);

                if (ddSchemeCode.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    lblCreated.Visible = true;
                    lblUpdated.Visible = false;
                    DataClass.addNewSchemeCode(data);
                }

                if (ddSchemeCode.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddVersion.SelectedIndex != 0)
                {
                    lblCreated.Visible = true;
                    lblUpdated.Visible = false;
                    DataClass.addNewVersion(data);
                }

                if (ddSchemeCode.SelectedIndex != 0 && ddVersion.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    lblUpdated.Visible = true;
                    lblCreated.Visible = false;
                    DataClass.UpdateData(data);
                }
```

Here is the `TemplateData` class

```
    public class TemplateData
{
    public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
    public string TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string SchemeCode { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public TemplateData(string schemeCode, string version, string comment, string templateID, byte[] logo)
    {
        SchemeCode = schemeCode;
        Version = version;
        Comment = comment;
        TemplateId = templateID;
        Logo = logo;

    }

    public TemplateData(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        initialiseData();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
                Version = dr["Version"].ToString();
                Logo = (byte[])dr["Logo"];                 
                TemplateId = dr["TemplateId"].ToString();
                Comment = dr["Comment"].ToString();
                SchemeCode = dr["SchemeCode"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `logoPrvw.Value` is `null`, you probably don't want to create the data object or follow with the rest of your code. So maybe, your solution is as simple as:

```
if (logoPrvw.Value != null)
    return;

System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(logoPrvw.Value);
byte[] logoBytes;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    logoBytes = ms.ToArray();
}

TemplateData data = new TemplateData(txtSchemeCode.Text, txtVersion.Text, txtComment.Text, txtTemplateId.Text, logoBytes);

//rest of your code
```

Comment: - Edited Accordingly -
If there is no image in the path, it is because an image has been imported from a database and is already being displayed there

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to declare the `logoBytes` variable outside the `if` statement so that it's still in scope when you create the `TemplateData`. You need to decide what value it should have if there isn't a file provided. For example, you might want it to be `null`, or maybe an empty array. You could either give the variable an initial value, or use an `else` clause. Examples:

```
byte[] logoBytes = null;
if (logoPrvw.Value != null)
{
    ...
    // Code that assigns a different value to logoBytes
}
TemplateData data = new TemplateData(..., logoBytes);
```

or:

```
byte[] logoBytes;
if (logoPrvw.Value != null)
{
    ...
    // Code that assigns a value to logoBytes
}
else
{
    logoBytes = new byte[0];
}
TemplateData data = new TemplateData(..., logoBytes);
```

I would then recommend refactoring the "work out `logoBytes`" code into a separate method, so you'd have:

```
byte[] logoBytes = GetLogoBytes(logoPrvw);
TemplateData data = new TemplateData(...);
```

Then your `GetLogoBytes` method can just be something like:

```
byte[] GetLogoBytes(HtmlInputFile logoPrvw)
{
    if (logoPrvw.Value == null)
    {
        return null; // Or an empty array, or whatever
    }
    using (Image img = ...)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
           img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
           return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't want to use `Image.FromFile` - you want to use the data which is in the posted file, so probably `Image.FromStream(logoPrvw.PostedFile.InputStream)`

Comment: Hi Jon,
I can give you the control for `logoPrvw` on the front end aspx page... But I don't really know what type it would be. Other than that, it looks like it should work.

The control is just (as far as I know) a html tag:

`            <input ID="logoPrvw" type ="file" onchange="previewFile()" runat="server" />`

Comment: @Bigtingz92: You should be able to hover over `logPrvw` in the code to find out its type...

Comment: Gotcha! ;)
Told you I was a newbie, it's type HtmlInputFile, I'll give your code another run through now

Comment: Ok, surely when I initialize logoBytes to null, it will be null, so the if statement with the GetLogoBytes method in will never get executed?

Comment: @Bigtingz92: I have no idea what you mean by that. Do you understand that I've given you two *different* solutions here? One where the code is still all in the same method, and one where you extract the "convert logo to bytes" code into a separate method.

Comment: Yes, I understand I think. In method 1, logoBytes is initialized to null, Correct?

Comment: @Bigtingz92: Yes, although that value is then replaced if there's a logo.

Comment: Ok, I'm still pulling an error on line `System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(logoPrvw.Value);`

That says
"The path is not of a legal form"

Comment: @Bigtingz92: Ah yes - that's because you're trying to load the file on the *server* with the path that's on the *client*. You don't want to do that. You want to use `logoPrvw.PostedFile`.

Comment: Cheers for sticking with me Jon, 
I've popped `.PostedFile` in place of `.Value` and I'm getting a red squiggly. Some Invalid Arguments. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: @Bigtingz92: Yes, see my edited answer - and read the error message carefully. I don't want to be too down, but if you don't understand that error message, then fixing this one problem is just going to lead to another one, etc, and you should really get a good book and learn the basics - or get some mentoring from a colleague. Stack Overflow isn't an interactive pairing environment...